# Ruby, GNOME, 2D animation, sort of

Tags: ruby, gnome, cairo

I want to make a simple app to do simple animation.

Mostly a filled-circle/s rotating on a circular or ellipse path..
Something like planets rotating around a Sun.
The problem is there is not much information on internet except from some simple static drawing apps.

I want to use Ruby on GNOME.
From what I was able to find it seems that Cairo is the best way to do it.

My main question is do you have some advice or better an example how to do dynamic drawing with Cairo and Ruby.

thank you

Comment: there is nothing spectacular about doing animations. Its a simple process you just use a loop that erases your screen and places graphics in a new location. Viola you have an animation now :)

Answer (score 1):

For animation, I propose 3 other Ruby gems dedicated to animation :

- [Ruby 2D](http://www.ruby2d.com) by Tom Black
- [graphics](https://github.com/zenspider/graphics) by Ryan Davis.
- [gosu](https://www.libgosu.org) by Julian Raschke

Gosu is more mature, but the three are actively developed today (march 2017).

Answer (score 0):

I found another very easy small GUI framework... called Shoes :

http://shoesrb.com/

or better yet reworked version which can be easily installed 'gem install green_shoes' :

http://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/

but it will be good if I could still find a way to do 2D animation with Cairo.